# How to output error message if names are the same

Tags: java

guys just wondering if you know how to output error message if the names of doctors entered in the system exist already. All the help is great thanks.

```
public void addDoctor()throws IOException
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstname,job;

    System.out.println("name of doctor");
    firstname=console.next();
    if (firstname.contains(" ")) {
        System.err.println("doctors name must not have spaces!");
        run();
    }
    System.out.println("specialisation, dog or cat");
    job=console.next();
    if(!"dog".equals(job) && !"cat".equals(job)){
        System.err.println("specialisation must be dog or cat and doctors name must not have spaces");
        run();
    }
    if (totald < 4) {
        doc[totald]=new Doctor();
        doc[totald++].setDatad(firstname,job);
    }
    else {
        System.err.print("error, no more than 4 doctors allow in system\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the **equals** method and after that, you can put all doctors in Set. Once you have a new name you can check it from the Set.[how to override equals](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/can-we-override-the-equals-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ArrayList of doctor names:

```
ArrayList<String> doctorNames;
```

each time use before adding new name ( `doctorNames.add(firstName);` )

check if this name has already been added or not using:

```
doctorNames.contains(firstName)
```

Comment: would this work because I'm using console to add the doctors names not manually in the system.

Comment: Yes, you just have to get the  *firstName*  using console, and then add it to  *ArrayList doctorNames*  using your java code. (and of course before adding, check the ArrayList, to make sure it doesn't contain the name already)